# How to make <li> jump up and down using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a horizontal navigation menu with a "JOIN" item. I want the `#jump` item to jump up and down indefinitely soon after the page loads.

This gives the effect but only once and only upon hover:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#jump').hover(function(){
   $(this).animate({bottom:'5px'},'fast');
   }, function() {
   $(this).animate({bottom:'0px'},'fast');
   });
</script>
```

if I make it: `ready()` it stops working.

Comment: Adding $(document).ready() can help you alot :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why jquery  simply do with [`css animation`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwias8XMhv7TAhXLsY8KHf6rBKYQFggoMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcss%2Fcss3_animations.asp&usg=AFQjCNFi0jNn7YQFD70pd7oB_jG-0I11hg&sig2=bFQXDoHthYgc0FCbGH2MYw)

```css
#some{
border-radius:100%;
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:#ccc;
animation:top 0.3s ease-in infinite; /*change the animation transition effect as your wish*/
}

@keyframes top{
from{transform:translateY(0px);}
to{transform:translateY(10px);}
}
```

```html
<div id="some"></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$("#jump").slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000);
```

detail available at:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp